# SonarQube fails on Azure Pipelines with Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.InputComponentStore

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines, sonarqube-scan, azure-pipelines-yaml

After installing the marketplace plugin I'm following the [official documentation for my SonarQube installation (8.6 Community)](https://docs.sonarqube.org/8.6/analysis/azuredevops-integration/)

gradle plugin cfg:

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    id("org.sonarqube") version "3.1.1"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.21"
}
```

Here's a scerpt of the pipeline:

```
        - task: SonarQubePrepare@4
          inputs:
            SonarQube: 'profile-sonarqube'
            scannerMode: 'Other'
            extraProperties: |
              # Additional properties that will be passed to the scanner, 
              # Put one key=value per line, example:
              # sonar.exclusions=**/*.bin
              sonar.projectKey=hello-azure
        - task: Gradle@2
          inputs:
            gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
            tasks: 'build'
            publishJUnitResults: true
            testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
            javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
            sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
            sqGradlePluginVersionChoice: 'specify'
            sonarQubeGradlePluginVersion: '3.1.1'
        - task: SonarQubePublish@4
          inputs:
            pollingTimeoutSec: '300'
```

I've also tried setting sonar.branch=main and sonar.branch.name=main  as `extraProperties`.

This is the full log:

```
Starting: SonarQubePrepare
==============================================================================
Task         : Prepare Analysis Configuration
Description  : Prepare SonarQube analysis configuration
Version      : 4.17.0
Author       : sonarsource
Help         : Version: 4.17.0. [More Information](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-tfs-ts.html)
==============================================================================
Finishing: SonarQubePrepare

...

> Task :compileTestKotlin
> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE

> Task :sonarqube
SonarScanner will require Java 11 to run starting in SonarQube 8.x

> Task :sonarqube FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
> No branches currently exist in this project. Please scan the main branch without passing any branch parameters.
```

What's wrong here?

**UPDATE:**

Oddly enough, running the sonarqube gradle task manually as a pipeline script works ok:

```
- script: ./gradlew sonarqube -Dsonar.projectKey=hello-azure -Dsonar.host.url=https://mysonarqubeserver  -Dsonar.login=mylogin
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I changed the plugin version to 3.0

```
        - task: Gradle@2
          inputs:
            gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
            tasks: 'build'
            publishJUnitResults: true
            testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
            javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
            sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
            sqGradlePluginVersionChoice: 'specify'
            sonarQubeGradlePluginVersion: '3.0'
```

Now this is the behaviour:

- When the application hasn't been previously created on SonarQube, it works fine the first time.
- Subsequent builds fail with `Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.InputComponentStore`

Log:

```
> Task :sonarqube
SonarScanner will require Java 11 to run starting in SonarQube 8.x

> Task :sonarqube FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
> Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.InputComponentStore
```

Here's the full stacktrace where the root cause is `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SHORT`:

```
2021-02-17T22:52:41.8616402Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.799+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
2021-02-17T22:52:41.8617730Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.800+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.InputComponentStore
2021-02-17T22:52:41.8618768Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.800+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2021-02-17T22:52:41.8619739Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.800+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
2021-02-17T22:52:41.8620759Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.800+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  Run with --scan to get full insights.
2021-02-17T22:52:41.8621690Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.800+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2021-02-17T22:52:41.8622648Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.800+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9079864Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.802+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9081980Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.803+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:200)
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9083995Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.803+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263)
...
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9577148Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.849+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.scanner.scan.branch.BranchConfiguration
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9578725Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.849+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:66)
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9580213Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.849+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9581700Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.849+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9583224Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.849+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9584690Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.849+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9586243Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.849+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9587728Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.849+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9589239Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.849+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9637580Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.849+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9639629Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.850+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9641227Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.850+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9642650Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.850+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9644254Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.850+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9645676Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.850+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9647288Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.850+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9648493Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.851+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  ... 129 more
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9649561Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.851+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SHORT
...
2021-02-17T22:52:41.9729914Z 2021-02-17T22:52:41.851+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 1m 42s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SonarQube fails on Azure Pipelines with Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.InputComponentStore

It seems this issue is that the `SonarQube` version is not compatible with `Plugin Version Community Branch Plugin`.

You could try to use SonarQube Version: 8.1 and Plugin Version: Community Branch Plugin 1.3.0 (communityBranchPlugin).

**Note**： That a separate release is required for 8.2 and above due to further changes in those releases.

Please check the thread [SonarQube 8.1 Support](https://github.com/mc1arke/sonarqube-community-branch-plugin/pull/58) on the Github for some more details.